# Blank page when calling Javascript in HTML- what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do a basic google map link into HTML. When I place the code directly in HTML it works but when I try to link from external JS document I just get a blank page:

HTML Code:

```
 <html>
<head>
    <title>Search Engine Title Goes Here</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="twoColumn.css">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type=text/javascript src="myfile.js"

   </head>
<body>
    <div id="container"> </div>
    <div id="header"> Header Goes Here</div>
    <div id="sidebar"> Left Navigation Goes Here
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>

    </div>
    <div id="content"> <p>Content Goes Here</p></div>
    <div id="footer"> Footer Goes Here </div>
</body>
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: your script never ends with </script>

Comment: What do you mean with "link from external JS document"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You:

1. Forgot the `>` from the second script's start tag
2. Omitted the end tag from the second script

The consequence of the first isn't serious, the end tag for the `head` ends up being treated as an invalid attribute and then ends the tag.

The consequence of the second is that the *entire rest of the page* is parsed (with errors!) as JavaScript instead of being treated as HTML.

This would have been picked up if you had used [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/nu/).

Note that the `language` attribute was obsoleted when HTML 4 came out in 1998, and the `type` attribute was made optional (for JavaScript scripts) in HTML 5. Omit both of them, they bloat your code and just give you the chance to break the script with a typo.

Corrected version:

```
<script src="myfile.js"></script>
```

Comment: <script language="javascript" type=text/javascript src="myfile.js">

Comment: @viktor.svirskyy — That is how you fix the first of the two problems, yes.

Answer (score -2):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js"></script>
```

You should always include a closing script tag

**EDIT**: I also noticed that you missed the "" around `text/javascript`

Comment: Try this: <script type="text/javascript" src="myfile.js"></script>